# Why are these file sizes not normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I have saved 10,000 webcam images and tallied their lengths.  The lighting conditions were constant throughout the recording time. The probability distribution is shown here, with my best efforts at fitting a normal curve to it...

[image: File size probability distribution]

The files are created via multiple complicated processes of quantum mechanics, electronic theory, temperature and of course the JPEG encoding algorithm.  You can see that there is a skew to the distribution. This is apparent even without the curve fit.

Q. After 10,000 samples, why is the distribution not 'more' normal in accordance with the central limit theorem?

Comment: What does the CLT say?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, I assume that the images are from the same webcam and taken within a relatively short time. So they are certainly not independent, another assumption of the CLT.

Comment: "Everyone is sure of this [that errors are normally distributed], Mr. Lippman told me one day, since the experimentalists believe that it is a mathematical theorem, and the mathematicians that it is an experimentally determined fact."-Henri Poincaré

Comment: @cfh This worries me greatly for what I'm doing.  Yes it's the same camera over the course of 90 mins.  And yes the image was fixed.  But most of the other noise effects are independent surely, otherwise all the files would be the same size?  Also all the files themselves  are proved unique in content.

Comment: The skew could also be coming from the JPEG compression.  Remember that jpeg is essentially transforming the image to frequency space and discarding the high frequency components that are thought to be imperceptible for humans (for the most part).  A slight shift in color gradient in the image could lead to the collapsing of pixels colors as a result of the JPEG compression.  One way to test is to reduce the compression ratio in the JPEG and look for the skew to disappear.  But again, the independence of the image samples doesn't mean their file size distribution will be normal.

Answer (score 8):

CLT applies to the mean of samples from a distribution. If you bootstrap the mean of your data you'll find that the distribution of the mean of your data is normal. The file sizes of the images are neither generated under these conditions, nor do they have the assumptions in which the CLT apply, so it's not expected that the distribution be normal.

Comment: I'd say 'looks normal' or "is approximately normal" rather than assert that it "is normal". Indeed we can be confident means of finite random samples from a non-normal population will not themselves be normal.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look of the definition for Central-Limit-Theorem:

[image]

This statement tells us that you only get a normal distribution for the sample means given enough sample size. There is no assumption to the underlying distribution that it needs to be normal.

Comment: On the contrary, for the conclusion of the CLT to be true, strong assumptions have to be made about the underlying distribution.  Among them are that it has a finite variance and its components are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

The standard central limit theorem holds under some conditions, one of which is **independance of observed events**. Were these captured images in such a way that parameters of the images had no correlations between them ?

It's kind of reassuring to think that if you were filming a periodic phenomenon (say, the position of the sun at the same time every day), you wouldn't end up with a normal distribution in parameters of the images.

There are some other theorems showing that convergence to the normal distribution still occurs when events are not totally uncorrelated. These theorems rely on complex hypotheses, some of them stating that observed events have to be "not too much correlated".